# How virtual machine detect the application window?

Tags: windows, winapi

Here is a screenshot of VMware fusion...
[image: http://www.vmware.com/files/images/screens_fusion/f5/Mission-Control-Widescreen-580x363.jpg]

As you can see, they can simulate the Windows application like a OS X application. I know there is many technology behind, but something that I would like to do: (**Any** language that can solve follow problems is welcome, but **prefer python**. )

1. How to detect how many window is running on Windows?
2. How to detect each window's width and height?

Comment: I fear you may have bitten off more than you can chew. Application redirection is a very hard problem. Finding the windows is just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Call [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) to enumerate the top level windows.
2. Call [`IsWindowVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530.aspx) for each of those windows to test whether or not the window is visible.
3. Call [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519.aspx) to find out a window's position.

In Python you can do all this with the `win32api` module.

I must confess that I cannot understand the relationship between VMware Fusion and the two questions you asked.